# Executor lost failure: Host was preempted

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, executor

My spark streaming application (running on HD Insights) constantly has tasks failing due to the error message below:

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 525 exited unrelated to the running tasks) Reason: Container container_1495825717937_0056_01_000916 on host: 10.0.0.14 was preempted.
```

Do you have any ideas what I should do here? It is not obvious to me how I should act upon this error message.

Comment: You should have a look at HDInsights (YARN) logs as it's likely that more important application requested resources and yours got less.